# Json Web Signature and Json Web Signature Objective C library

Tags: objective-c, jwt, json-web-token

I had cross some library with previous code in Java. The problem i cannot find JSONWebSignature and JSONWebEncyption Library in Objective C.

Wonder how to achieve the below code in Obj C:

```
//generate JWT Token
public static Map<String, String> generateJWT(String pubKey, RSAPrivateKey privKey, String keyID, 
                                        String issuer, String audience, int expireTime, int nbf, String subject, String ev){
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {    
        RsaJsonWebKey eStatementJWK =  (RsaJsonWebKey)PublicJsonWebKey.Factory.newPublicJwk(pubKey);//pubKeyCache.getIfPresent(bhCode)
        eStatementJWK.setKeyId("rk1");

        JwtClaims claims = new JwtClaims();
        claims.setIssuer(issuer);  // who creates the token and signs it
        claims.setAudience(audience); // to whom the token is intended to be sent
        claims.setExpirationTimeMinutesInTheFuture(expireTime); // time when the token will expire (10 minutes from now)
        claims.setGeneratedJwtId(); // a unique identifier for the token
        claims.setIssuedAtToNow();  // when the token was issued/created (now)                
        claims.setNotBeforeMinutesInThePast(nbf); // time before which the token is not yet valid (10 minutes ago)
        claims.setSubject(subject); // the subject/principal is whom the token is about
        claims.setClaim("ev",ev); // additional claims/attributes about the subject can be added

        // A JWT is a JWS and/or a JWE with JSON claims as the payload.
        // In this example it is a JWS nested inside a JWE
        // So we first create a JsonWebSignature object.
        JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();

        //The payload of the JWS is JSON content of the JWT Claims
        jws.setPayload(claims.toJson());
        jws.setKey(privKey);
        jws.setKeyIdHeaderValue("sk1");

        // Set the signature algorithm on the JWT/JWS that will integrity protect the claims
        jws.setAlgorithmHeaderValue(AlgorithmIdentifiers.RSA_USING_SHA256);

        // Sign the JWS and produce the compact serialization, which will be the inner JWT/JWS
        // representation, which is a string consisting of three dot ('.') separated
        // base64url-encoded parts in the form Header.Payload.Signature
        String innerJwt = jws.getCompactSerialization();

        // The outer JWT is a JWE
        JsonWebEncryption jwe = new JsonWebEncryption();

        // The output of the ECDH-ES key agreement will encrypt a randomly generated content encryption key
        jwe.setAlgorithmHeaderValue(KeyManagementAlgorithmIdentifiers.RSA_OAEP);

        // The content encryption key is used to encrypt the payload
        // with a composite AES-CBC / HMAC SHA2 encryption algorithm
        String encAlg = ContentEncryptionAlgorithmIdentifiers.AES_128_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256;
        jwe.setEncryptionMethodHeaderParameter(encAlg);

        // We encrypt to the receiver using their public key
        jwe.setKey(eStatementJWK.getPublicKey());
        jwe.setKeyIdHeaderValue(eStatementJWK.getKeyId());    
        jwe.setHeader("keyID",keyID);

        // A nested JWT requires that the cty (Content Type) header be set to "JWT" in the outer JWT
        jwe.setContentTypeHeaderValue("JWT");

        // The inner JWT is the payload of the outer JWT
        jwe.setPayload(innerJwt);

        // Produce the JWE compact serialization, which is the complete JWT/JWE representation,
        // which is a string consisting of five dot ('.') separated
        // base64url-encoded parts in the form Header.EncryptedKey.IV.Ciphertext.AuthenticationTag
        String jwt = jwe.getCompactSerialization();

        // Now you can do something with the JWT. Like send it to some other party
        // over the clouds and through the interwebs.
        System.out.println("JWT="+jwt);

        result.put("s", "200");
        result.put("v", jwt);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        result.put("s", "500");
        result.put("v", e.getMessage());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hope someone able to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is Java and it returns a HashMap.  In Obj-C you'd probably want to use an NSDictionary for this.

```
NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[result setObject: @"200" forKey: @"s"];
[result setObject: SomeObject forKey: @"v"];

return result;
```